# The output voltage of my atmega16 is zero?

Tags: avr, avrdude

I'm write a simple program with winavr:

```c
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#ifndef F_CPU
#define F_CPU 1000000
#endif
int main (void)
{
void init(void);
while(1){

PORTA = 0xff;
PORTB = 0xff;
PORTC = 0xff;
PORTD = 0xff;
_delay_ms(500);

PORTD = 0x00;
PORTA = 0x00;
PORTB = 0x00;
PORTC = 0x00;
_delay_ms(500);
}
return 0;
}
void init (void)
{
//  Enable Interrupts
sei();
DDRA = 0xff;
PORTA = 0xff;
//  Port b0-3 Initialization to statuse led 
DDRB = 0xff;
PORTB = 0x00;
//  Port C1-7 Initialization to led outpot
DDRC = 0xff;
PORTC = 0x00;
//  Port D4-7 Initialization to key input
DDRD = 0xff;
PORTD = 0xff;
}
```

I use usbasp for program and IC is new . all work is good and programer report no error but when connect a led to one pin of each ports the blinky led is very low light and the output voltage of pin is low too.
Have any suggestion about this problem ? IC damaged?...

Comment: What is your supply voltage, the colour of your LED and the series resistor value you are using with it?

Comment: _delay_ms should be necessarily called with a delay of less than 262 milliseconds at 1MHz, and lower than that for higher frequencies.

Comment: If you want to measure the output voltage simply, modify the program to turn the LED on constantly.  Otherwise you'll need to do the voltage measurement with something like an oscilloscope instead of a voltmeter.

Comment: thx for you!
the answers are good.
the micro use output of usbasp pin as power input. and equal ~ 4.99 volt. i define F_cpu in makefile and define #ifndef in main.c file then the second F_cpu not important.
the new micro have 1MHz too!!! The important note is my blinky program is running and isn't important for me about how long between on/off time, the output of pin when become 1 is <2 volt. why?

Answer (score 3):

> all work is good and programer report no error but when connect a led to one pin of each ports the blinky led is very low light and the output voltage of pin is low too. Have any suggestion about this problem ? IC damaged?

Since we don't know any of the specifications of your setup, I won't be able to go into too much detail. However, the good news is that everything sounds like it is working.

---

The voltage that a pin will produce, depends on the input voltage for the AtMega16 it'self. (There are some exceptions, like port A, etc. but I'll keep this basic.) So if the MCU is powered by 3vDc and should expect to see 3v on an output pin that is active.

The maximum current the AtMega16 can source (provide) is 20mA. This isn't too much. This is why people usually use a transistor that is triggered by a Atmega pin, to control devices that need more power. Here is an example of using a transistor:

[image]

**Since we don't know what type of LED you are using and what it's specs are, the fact that you can see it blinking is great! Even though it's dim, it sounds like you have everything up and working.** I should also point out that `F_CPU 1000000` is the frequency that the chip is running at. If the chip is new and you don't have it connected to an external clock source, then I believe you have the setting correct. Most AtMega's come with and internal 8Mhz oscillator and a clock divide by 8 fuse set so the default operating frequency is 1Mhz.

As @ChintalagiriShashank said, `delay_ms()` should be used with values less than 262ms/MHz. Here is the excerpt from the [AVR-GCC Documentation](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__util__delay.html):

> The maximal possible delay is 262.14 ms / F_CPU in MHz.
>
> When the user request delay which exceed the maximum possible one,
>   _delay_ms() provides a decreased resolution functionality. In this mode _delay_ms() will work with a resolution of 1/10 ms, providing
>   delays up to 6.5535 seconds (independent from CPU frequency). The user
>   will not be informed about decreased resolution.
>
> If the avr-gcc toolchain has __builtin_avr_delay_cycles(unsigned long)
>   support, maximal possible delay is 4294967.295 ms/ F_CPU in MHz. For
>   values greater than the maximal possible delay, overflows results in
>   no delay i.e., 0ms.

Here is a cleaner version of your code, it only works with Port B though.

```c
int main (void)
{
    DDRB = 0xff; // Set Data Direction for port B as output
    sei();  //  Enable Interrupts
    while(1){
        PORTB = 0xff; // 'turn on' all port B pins
        _delay_ms(250);
        _delay_ms(250);
        PORTB = 0x00; // Clear all port B pins
        _delay_ms(250);
        _delay_ms(250);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

**Addendum**

As [AngryEE pointed out](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/56354/9730), you need to also need to define `F_CPU` **BEFORE** `#include <util/delay.h>`. Like this:

```
#define F_CPU 1000000
#include <util/delay.h>
```

Comment: Please expand on "some exceptions, like port A, etc" thank you.

Comment: @ExcitingProjects I don't have a datasheet, but I *think*, on that chip you can have a different `AVCC` input voltage that will power the analog side. Also, I was thinking about thinks like ADCs DACs, but didn't want to go into much detail about why an output pin can have different voltages.

Answer (score 1):

F_CPU must be defined BEFORE including delay.h.  Otherwise your timing will be off.  That is almost certainly a part of your problem.

Comment: It bit me too.  I must say it's odd that it works like that but I think F_CPU is preferably supposed to be set with a command-line define and not with a #define in the code

Comment: I FOUND the problem!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Although you've posted an answer, you haven't explained why you're seeing this.

The code

```
int main (void)
{
 void init(void);
```

declares a void -> void function called `init` , rather than calling the function void. A function declaration inside a function definition is perfectly valid in C or C++, so you won't get a warning or error. Multiple declarations within a 'compilation unit' (the file and all the files it includes) are not an error as long as they are compatible.

Because your `init` function is declared but not called, the ports are all left as inputs.

This code is run in the loop

```
PORTA = 0xff;
PORTB = 0xff;
PORTC = 0xff;
PORTD = 0xff;
```

Setting PORTx has different behaviour depending whether the port is output or input.

For an input port, it enables the internal pull-up resistors. On the Atmega16 these are between 20kΩ and 50kΩ.

So you're alternately connecting the LED to 5V through several tens of kΩ, and it will be less bright than desired.

Answer (score 0):

I FOUND the problem!!!!!!
The problem not about wrong F-cpu, _delay_ms(), led type, input voltage ...
I forget a note:

```
int main (void)
{
 void init(void);
 while(1){...
```

in this function init() must be before main function

```
**void init (void);**
int main (void)
{
 init();
 while(1){...
```

the problem fixed and thanks for all (even for persons give my question "-" or for persons not ready my question careful !!!!

Comment: You didn't get a compiler error or warning for that? Hmm. FYI you don't need to have an `init` section, You can just put in inside main, but before the while loop. Then your code would look more like the code in [my answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/56320/9730)

Answer (score 0):

Your pin is already set to input.  Not output.
You have to use this statement: `DDRA=0x01;`